# How To Print Multiple Pages Programatically?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an app that displays transcripts, something like this myapp.com/transcript/1234  The transcripts are formatted so they can just be printed from the browser (ctrl+p).

What should I do to allow the users to be able to print multiple transcripts without visiting each page?  e.g.  Print transcripts for every user in group B.

Should I create a new view that just displays all of the requested transcripts at once?
Do I now have to look into creating PDFs?  (shoot me)
Other thoughts?

Comment: FYI, there's no need to put "ASP MVC" in the title, since it's in the tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, create/change a view to display all the transcripts to be printed. Wrap each transcript in a container with a style class (like a div, <div class="transcript">...</div>). Use CSS to style each container such that a page-break occurs for each transcript. The style will look something like the following.

```
.transcript: {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally just create pdfs. Using it for things such as official time sheets and various other forms I can't change. It is actually very simple to do with itextsharp and if your PDF has properly labeled input fields (aka isn't just one big scanned image or something).

Comment: I think this is the next logical step but it isnt something I want to do unless I have to.